# Analysis proof (compactness)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, compactness

Let $A$ $\subseteq$ $\mathbb{R}^n$ be compact, and let $F: A \to \mathbb{R}^m$, be a continuous mapping. Prove $F(A)$ is compact.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Wow, yeah, this is a duplicate of that. Sorry about the repeat!